# How can I remove markers from the map using the checkboxes on the left?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet, react-leaflet

Here is my work in progress app. My aim is to show surfing spots on a map with its current wind speeds and its difficulty level (based on how high the wind speed is)

https://lewisd1996.github.io/surferspotter/

I am new to React and I'm still learning as I go.

***How can I change the markers on the map with my check-boxes on the left.***

**Here is my SurfMap class:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import main from '../styles/main.scss';
import SpotList from "./SpotList.js";
import Spot from "./Spot.js";
import axios from 'axios';
import jsonLocations from '../jsonLocations.json';

export default class SurfMap extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            spots: [], //THE ARRAY THAT WILL HOLD THE LIST OF SURFING SPOTS
        }
        }

    getSpots = () => { //THE FUNCTION TO POPULATE THE LIST OF SPOTS USING AXIOS

       axios.get("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e8733f193960d63f0782ad5/2")
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                spots: res.data
            });
        });

    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getSpots();
    }

    render() {
        var startPosition = [36.778259, -119.417931] //STARTING POSITION OF THE MAP
        return (
            <>
            {this.state.spots.length ? 
                <Map className="map" center={startPosition} zoom={5}>
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                        />
                    {this.state.spots.map (spot => //LOOP THROUGH THE LIST OF SPOTS AND CREATE A SPOT FOR EACH ONE TO BE PLOTTED ONTO THE MAP
                        <Spot {...spot} />
                    )}
                </Map>:
        <p>loading data....</p>}
      </>

        )
    }
}
```

**Here is my Spot class (the spots to go surf that are plotted on the map):**

```
import React, { Component, setState } from 'react'
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';
import axios from 'axios';
import main from '../styles/main.scss'

var owmApiKey = 'HIDING THIS FROM STACKOVERFLOW';

var beginnerIcon = L.icon({ //SETS UP THE PIN ICON THAT IS USED TO PLOT MARKERS ON THE MAP
    iconUrl: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/markers/Green-marker.png',
    iconSize: [41,41],
    iconAnchor: [12.5,41],
    popupAnchor: [0, -41]
});

var intIcon = L.icon({ //SETS UP THE PIN ICON THAT IS USED TO PLOT MARKERS ON THE MAP
    iconUrl:  process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/markers/Red-marker.png',
    iconSize: [41,41],
    iconAnchor: [12.5,41],
    popupAnchor: [0, -41]
});

var expertIcon = L.icon({ //SETS UP THE PIN ICON THAT IS USED TO PLOT MARKERS ON THE MAP
    iconUrl: process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/markers/Purple-marker.png',
    iconSize: [41,41],
    iconAnchor: [12.5,41],
    popupAnchor: [0, -41]
});


export default class Spot extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super()
        this.state = {
            county_name: props.county_name,
            latitude: props.latitude,
            longitude: props.longitude,
            spot_id: props.spot_id,
            spot_name: props.spot_name,
            wind_speed: 0,
        }
    }

    getWindSpeed = (latitude, longitude) => {//THE FUNCTION TO POPULATE THE LIST OF SPOTS USING AXIOS
            axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude}&lon=${latitude}&appid=${owmApiKey}`)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    wind_speed: (res.data.wind.speed * 1.944)
                });
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getWindSpeed(this.state.latitude,this.state.longitude);
    }


    render() {
        return(
        <>
            {(() => {
            if (this.state.wind_speed < 8) {
                return (
                    <Marker position={[this.state.latitude,this.state.longitude]} icon={beginnerIcon} className="beginner-marker">
                    <Popup >
                        <p className="marker-label">{this.state.spot_name + ", " + this.state.county_name}<br/>Wind Speed: {this.state.wind_speed} knots<br/>Difficulty: Beginner</p>
                    </Popup>
                    </Marker>    
                )
            } else if (this.state.wind_speed > 8 && this.state.wind_speed < 16) {
                return (
                    <Marker position={[this.state.latitude,this.state.longitude]} icon={intIcon}  className="intermediate-marker">
                    <Popup >
                        <p className="marker-label">{this.state.spot_name + ", " + this.state.county_name}<br/>Wind Speed: {this.state.wind_speed} knots<br/>Difficulty: Intermediate</p>
                    </Popup>
                    </Marker>    
                )
            } else {
                return (
                    <Marker position={[this.state.latitude,this.state.longitude]} icon={expertIcon}  className="expert-marker">
                    <Popup >
                        <p className="marker-label">{this.state.spot_name + ", " + this.state.county_name}<br/>Wind Speed: {this.state.wind_speed} knots<br/>Difficulty: Expert</p>
                    </Popup>
                    </Marker>   
                )
            }
            })()}
            </>
        )
    }

}
```

**My check-boxes are held in my control panel class:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import main from '../styles/main.scss';

export default class ControlPanel extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="control-panel">
                <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"></input>
                    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineCheckbox1">Novice</label>
                </div>

                <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"></input>
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineCheckbox2">Intermediate</label>
                </div>

                <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"></input>
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineCheckbox3">Expert</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**And my Map and Control Panel are both put into my dashboard and that's then rendered in the App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import main from '../styles/main.scss'
import SurfMap from './SurfMap.js'
import ControlPanel from './ControlPanel.js';
import Spot from './Spot.js';
import SpotList from './SpotList.js';

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="dashboard">
                <div className="dashboard__control-panel">
                    <ControlPanel />
                </div>
                    <SurfMap />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to store the levels' state using context or redux since you want to share variables between components with no parent child relationship.

Here is an approach using context. Here is your Provider. It is going to store the checkboxes' state.

```
class Provider extends Component {
  state = {
    difficulty: {
      novice: true,
      beginner: true,
      intermediate: false,
      expert: false
    }
  };

  setDifficulty = difficulty => {
    this.setState({ difficulty });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Context.Provider
        value={{
          difficulty: this.state.difficulty,
          setDifficulty: this.setDifficulty
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Then you want to change the levels state locally on ControlPanel and once this is done update your global context:

```
 class ControlPanel extends Component {

      state = { novice: true, beginner: true, intermediate: false, expert: false };

      handleInputChange = event => {
        const target = event.target;
        const checked = target.checked;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
          [name]: checked
        });

        const difficulty = { ...this.state };
        difficulty[name] = checked;
        this.props.setDifficulty(difficulty);
      };

      render() {
        const levels = ["novice", "beginner", "intermediate", "expert"];

        return (
          <div className="control-panel">
            {levels.map(level => (
              <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input
                  className="form-check-input"
                  type="checkbox"
                  name={level}
                  checked={this.state[level]}
                  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                />
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineCheckbox1">
                  {level}
                </label>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default props => (
      <Context.Consumer>
        {({ setDifficulty }) => (
          <ControlPanel {...props} setDifficulty={setDifficulty} />
        )}
      </Context.Consumer>
    );
```

On SurfMap make context available:

```
....

 <>
    <Context.Consumer>
            {({ difficulty }) =>
              this.state.spots.map((
                spot,
                spotIndex //LOOP THROUGH THE LIST OF SPOTS AND CREATE A SPOT FOR EACH ONE TO BE PLOTTED ONTO THE MAP
              ) => (
                <Spot key={spotIndex} {...spot} difficulty={difficulty} />
              ))
            }
          </Context.Consumer>
        </>

...
```

finally on `Spot` comp use proper conditionals to render markers conditionally. fi if `wind_speed` is < 4.2 is a novice, if `wind_speed` is < 8 is a beginner etc and goes on:

```
    ....
        render() {
        const { spot_name, county_name, wind_speed } = this.state;
        const {
          difficulty: { novice, beginner, intermediate, expert }
        } = this.props;

        const marker = (
          <Marker
            position={[this.state.latitude, this.state.longitude]}
            icon={beginnerIcon}
            className="beginner-marker"
          >
            <Popup>
              <p className="marker-label">
                {spot_name + ", " + county_name}
                <br />
                Wind Speed: {wind_speed} knots
                <br />
                Difficulty:
                {wind_speed < 4.2
                  ? "Novice"
                  : wind_speed < 8
                  ? "Beginner"
                  : wind_speed > 8
                  ? "Intermediate"
                  : "Expert"}
              </p>
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        );

        if (novice && !beginner) return wind_speed < 4.2 && marker;
        else if (!novice && beginner)
          return wind_speed >= 4.2 && wind_speed < 8 && marker;
        else if (novice && beginner) return wind_speed < 8 && marker;
        return null;
      }
...
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-remove-markers-using-react-leaflet-from-the-map-using-the-checkboxes-on-the-left-jcwpm)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the marker dynamically you have to set a flag on marker json, so if the user press the checkbox you just play on re-rendering on marker json with a flag that get from checkbox.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure how this would work. Surely it's easier just to check which checkboxes are checked and remove those markers from the list rather than adding more info into the JSON file?